# centering a div vertically breaks on refresh

Tags: jquery, html

I am centering a div vertically in another div using the following code:

```
 var heightf = $('.cx1').height();
 var heightg = $('.cx2').height();
 heighth = (heightf - heightg) / 2;
 if (heighth > 0) {
    $('.cx2').css({ "marginTop": heighth });
 }
```

I have this within a document ready wrapper, and a window resize wrapper so that as the screen size changes the image remains centered (responsive).

This seems to work fine in all browsers, however when I refresh on Chrome and Kindle Fire, the div gets pushed down to the bottom rather than remaining in the center.

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: I suggest you try and do this centering bit from CSS

Comment: I have tried this using display:table for the main div, and display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; for the inner div, but that doesn't work (remains top aligned). Is there an alternative method? I always have trouble with centering vertically.

Comment: Just to demo the concept. This may help: http://jsfiddle.net/CaWkr/1/

Comment: Summary: `display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;` must be specified for the **outer** DIV for vertical alignment.

Comment: For some reason this doesn't work. Will any of the below cause a problem. 1) There are two inner divs inside the outer div. One contains text, the other an image (which is what I am trying to centre). 2) The image height isn't determined, as it is set as width:100% - and the height is determined by the aspect ratio of the image.

IE <div class="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;"><div>(text)</div><div>(image)</div></div>

Comment: Can you make a fiddle out of what you currently have?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see all the code that you have, so I can't tell why it would do that in Chrome (because my code doesn't do it).

It might be possible that you have a "collapsing margin" for the two divs.  You can add a `padding: 1px 0` to the outer div so that the vertical margins don't collapse.

I think you use a window resize handler because your outer div is tied to the size of the window?  So I make it the same height as the window in the following code.

This code works on Chrome on a Mac:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<style>
    body { margin: 0; }
    .wrapper { position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 100%;}
    .cx1 { background: dodgerblue; height: 100%; width: 300px; padding: 1px 0; }
    .cx2 { background: #ffc; height: 256px; width: 200px;}

</style>


<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="cx1">
        <div class="cx2">
            hello
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

    function verticallyCenter() {
        var heightf = $('.cx1').height();
        var heightg = $('.cx2').height();
        heighth = (heightf - heightg) / 2;
        if (heighth > 0) {
            $('.cx2').css({ "marginTop": heighth });
        }
    }

    $(verticallyCenter);

    $(window).resize(verticallyCenter);

</script>
```

Comment: Hi - This does work, but it doesn't work in my code. I am guessing it is because it has to load an image (size undetermined - width 100% of the container) and the code is executed before the image is loaded, thus the div changes in size after the function is called. I can kind of fix this by putting a setTimeOut on the function, but is there a better way?

Comment: then can't you set an "onload" handler for the image?  but if you have unknown size of an image, then yes, the CSS should handle it better

Comment: In the end I used an onload handler, but to make this work cross browser, I had to put a parameter on the end of the image tag inside the div to ensure that it didn't come from the cache, otherwise the onload wasn't fired.